# Django | Error al hacer más de una consulta a la vez y Return a template

Tags: python, django

Al tratar de hacer dos consultas o filters para enviar al template y mostrar los datos, me devuelve error. ¿Es posible enviar dos consultas a la vez al template?

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código:**

```
class StationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Station
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cuadro_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.kwargs['pk'],tipo_dispositivo=6 or 7 or 8)
        context2 = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context2['disp_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.kwargs['pk'],tipo_dispositivo=1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5)
        return context, context2
```

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer, pero debes retornar un diccionario y estas retornando una tupla....

Comment: por que necesitas dos contextos?
Y si en vez de usar dos contextos solo usas 1?, no recuerdo bien, pero según yo solo puedes retornar un diccionario, no dos.

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener un solo objeto context, context es un objeto tipo diccionario, es como un vector, solo que en vez de llamar a los elementos por su indice se les llama por un identificador, que en este caso son 'cuadro_list' y 'disp_list'

```
class StationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Station
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cuadro_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.kwargs['pk'],tipo_dispositivo=6 or 7 or 8)
        context['disp_list'] = Dispositivo.objects.filter(estacion=self.kwargs['pk'],tipo_dispositivo=1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5)
        return context
```